# Reading in arbitrary amount of binary messages

Tags: haskell, binary, monads

I am parsing binary data out of files using Binary.Get and have something like the following:

```
data FileMessageHeaders = FileMessageHeaders [FileMessageHeader]

data FileMessageHeader = FileMessageHeader ...

instance Binary FileMessageHeaders where
  put = undefined
  get = do
    messages <- untilM get isEmpty
    return (FileMessageHeaders messages)

instance Binary FileMessageHeader where
  put = undefined
  get = ..
```

The problem I am having is that the untilM from monad-loops on hackage uses sequence so I believe that this is what is causing a massive delay in returning the head of the FileMessageHeader list as the whole file must be read (is this correct?). I am having trouble coming up with a way to rewrite this and avoid sequencing all of the FileMessageHeaders in the file. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Stylistic note: Use a `newtype` or a simple `type`, when you are just wrapping something. The compiler is allowed to remove `newtype`s.

Comment: Half-baked answer: Use lazy IO, use iteratees, or incrementally return results and read out the next record when you're ready to deal with it (a less safe but more understandable version of iteratees.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FUZxxl notes, the problem is `untilM`; the `Get` monad is strict and requires that the entire `untilM` action completes before it returns.  IO has nothing to do with it.

The easiest thing to do is probably switch to [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) and use that for parsing instead of binary.  Attoparsec supports streaming parses and would likely be much easier to use for this case.

If you can't switch to attoparsec, you'll need to use some of the lower-level functions of binary rather than just using the `Binary` instance.  Something like the following (completely untested).

```
getHeaders :: ByteString -> [FileMessageHeader]
getHeaders b = go b 0
  where
    go bs n
      | B.null bs = []
      | otherwise = let (header, bs', n') = runGetState get bs n
                    in header : go bs' n'
```

Unfortunately this means you won't be able to use the `Binary` instance or the `get` function, you'll have to use `getHeaders`.  It will stream though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that an `IO` action has to finish before the control flow can continue. Thus, the program has to read in all the messages, before they get evaluated. You could try to define an own combinator `sequenceI`, that uses the function [`unsafeInterleaveIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v%3aunsafeInterleaveIO) from `System.IO.Unsafe`. This function allows you, well, to interleave actions. It is used, for instance by `getContents`. I would define `sequenceI` like this:

```
sequenceI (x:xs) = do v <- x
                      vs <- unsafeInterleaveIO $ sequenceI xs
                      return (v:vs)
```

On top of this combinator, you can define your own `untilM`, that streams. Doing this is left as an excercise to the reader.

#### Edit (corrected for compilation)

This is a proof-of-concept, untested implementation of untilM:

```
untilMI f p = do
  f' <- f
  p' <- p
  if p'
    then return [f']
    else do g' <- unsafeInterleaveIO $ untilMI f p
            return (f' : g')
```

Comment: I'm trying to redefine untilM using that as the underlying, but I am having trouble with the types lining up, I keep on getting "Couldn't match expected type IO a0 with actual type Get t0" Any idea how I can deal with this? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it working, but I'm still having trouble with the types. I replaced untilM with untilMI and I got "Couldn't match expected type `Get t0' with actual type `IO [a0]'" I tried using liftIO in front of untilMI and got "Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' with actual type `Get t0'" Does anybody know how I can get unsafeInterleaveIO to work with the get monad?

Comment: Ratzes: I missread the type signature. Should work now. But I see one more problem: Since `get` can work in any monad, `unsafePerformIO` is too specialized...

Comment: Yeah, I actually missed removing the f in the previous edit, so the above code is what I was trying to run with when I got those errors.

Comment: The only solution that I can come up with is to redefine FileMessageHeaders as Empty | (FileMessageHeader: FileMessageHeaders) whatever the syntax would be. Other than that, I'm completely at a loss for how to do this.

Comment: hm... Could you post some more code? That could help me to get something that runs.

Comment: @FUZxxl: you're correct to look to `untilM`, but your answer mixes up IO with other monads and is misleading for this problem.  In particular, `unsafePerformIO` can't be applied at all.  Hence the downvote.

Comment: @John See my comment above. I was a bit tired yesterday, so maybe I expressed myself a bit unclear.

Comment: @Ratzes: you can't use `unsafeInterleaveIO` with the `Get` monad.  `Get` doesn't involve IO at all.  This approach will not work.